# How to use Processing in Pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x

I know how to add processing files to the eclipse IDE, but is there a way to do that in PyCharm?

I get the files from this website: https://processing.org, I add the files into eclipse like this: http://gigl.scs.carleton.ca/node/48

Comment: I don't know about this `Processing` in particular, but since they seem to be under SVN, you can [use Pycharm's SVN integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/using-subversion-integration.html)

Comment: Is there a good tutorial on how I could do this?

Comment: In the left menu of the page I shared above, you can find several how-tos. Eventually, [how to checkout](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/checking-out-files-from-subversion-repository.html) will be the one of interest. But before that, if you are not familiar with SVN or version control in general, I highly recommend reading a bit about it online, if only to get a basic understanding of the underlying concepts.

Comment: Oh guys it is not SVN issue. @user6591409 asked that "how to use processing as a python library".

Answer (score 0):

You can use processing in python by importing the p5 library in python. But before you import that you need to add the openGL precompiled files to your System.path.
[Use this link to get reference](https://p5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)